# Issue with animations from an atlas in Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, animation, phaser-framework

I've been attempting to learn Phaser 3 so I can support my students in learning the framework. I've been able to get a spritesheet working, however, I'd prefer to use a json file, so I'm using the load atlas instead. The problem I'm having no matter what I try is that the update method is giving an error when I attempt to play the animation I created in the create method.

It says, **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'frame' of undefined**

I'm exporting my json and spritesheet using LeshyLabs https://www.leshylabs.com/apps/sstool/

Here's my code. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
<!doctype html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>First Phaser Game</title>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.11.0/dist/phaser.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var config = {
        type: Phaser.AUTO,
        width: 1200,
        height: 800,
        physics: {
          default: 'arcade',
          arcade: {
              gravity: { y: 300 },
              debug: false
          }
        },
        scene: {
            preload: preload,
            create: create,
            update: update
        }
    };

    var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
    var platforms;
    var cursors;
    var megaman;
    
    function addPlatform(x,y,width){
      for (i=0;i<width;i++){
        platforms.create(x+(i*64), y, 'ground');
      }
    }
    
    function preload()
    {
      this.load.image('bg', 'assets/ripbgzsnes03.png');
      this.load.image('ground', 'assets/platform.png');
      this.load.image('star', 'assets/star.png');
      this.load.image('bomb', 'assets/bomb.png');
      this.load.atlas('megaman', 'assets/spritesheet.png', 'assets/megamansprites2.json');
    }

    function create()
    {
      this.bg = this.add.image(2400,config.height/2,'bg');
      this.bg.displayWidth = 4800;
      this.bg.displayHeight = config.height;
      this.physics.world.bounds.width = 4800;
      platforms = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
      addPlatform(0, 580, 40);
    
      this.physics.add.collider(megaman, platforms);
      this.anims.create({ 
        key:'standing', 
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNames('stand', {
          prefix:'stand', 
          end:7, 
          zeroPad: 2
        }),
        repeat: -1
      });
      
      megaman = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 450, 'megaman');
      megaman.setCollideWorldBounds(true);

      cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
        // set bounds so the camera won't go outside the game world
      this.cameras.main.setBounds(0, 0, 4800, config.heightInPixels);
        // make the camera follow the player
      this.cameras.main.startFollow(megaman);
    }

    function update()
    {
      megaman.play('standing')
      // if (cursors.left.isDown)
      // {
      //     megaman.setVelocityX(-250);

      //     // megaman.anims.play('running', true);
      // }
      // else if (cursors.right.isDown)
      // {
      //     megaman.setVelocityX(250);

      //     // megaman.anims.play('running', true);
      // }
      // else
      // {
      //     megaman.setVelocityX(0);
      //     // megaman.play('standing');
      // }

      // if (cursors.up.isDown && megaman.body.touching.down)
      // {
      //     megaman.setVelocityY(-330);
      // }
      
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

In your load statement, you're naming the atlas `'megaman'` (name will be the first parameter passed into the load method). Then, in the `anims.create()` method, you're referencing an atlas called `'stand'` to generate the frame names. That's why you're getting undefined.

You can see an example of setting up animations with an atlas here: [Phaser Labs - Animation from Atlas](http://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src%5Canimation%5Ccreate%20animation%20from%20texture%20atlas.js).

In the meantime, if you change your create method to this, it should work:

```
this.anims.create({ 
    key:'standing', 
    frames: this.anims.generateFrameNames('megaman', {
        prefix:'stand', 
        end:7, 
        zeroPad: 2
    }),
    repeat: -1
});
```

Comment: I realize I never responded to this. Thanks for the quick response and I actually found the exact same issue, and then saw your response at the same time. Thank you!